# Operations in cells

Tags: matlab, matrix, cells

I have a cell 5x5 and each cell has 100x100 single data. I want to calculate the mode in each matrix 100x100 and then do some operations that depends on the mode. How Can I do this?

The cell:
[image]

Each cell has 100x100 data like this: [image]

I have this code that calculate the mode on each cell, now I want to compare each value on 100x100 matrix with corresponding cell mode.

```
I = imread('DSM.tif');
c = mat2cell(I, [100,100,100,100,100], [100,100,100,100,100])
for i=1:5
    for j=1:5
        mode_cell = mode(c{i,j}(:))
    end
end
```

I did this code:

```
modes = cellfun(@(x) mode(x(:)), c, 'UniformOutput', false);
modes = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) mode(x(:)), c, 'UniformOutput', false));
for i = 1 :5
for j =1 :5
    for i2=1 :100
        for j2=1 :100
            cell = c{i,j};
            if cell(i2,j2)<modes(i,j)
                teste(i,j)=0;
            else
                teste(i,j)=1;
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

But with this code the matrix teste is only 100x100. And I want to attach all testes matrix, and in the end I want an 500x500 matrix. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a for loop or cellfun, whatever you prefer.

Comment: I already have the mode of each cell. But how can I compare the value of each matrix 100x100 with the corresponding cell mode?

Comment: When asking questions, please make clear what you already understood and what you need. Now you received an answer and a comment explaining how to do what you already implement.

Comment: Yes I know, sorry about that. I realized that and edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit: Updated answer as per the update of your question

***Condensed solution `(+)`:***

```
%// data
I = imread('DSM.tif');
c = mat2cell(I, [100,100,100,100,100], [100,100,100,100,100])
    %// 5x5 cell matrix with 100x100 data entries

%// solution
teste = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) bsxfun(@ge, x, mode(x(:))), c, 'UniformOutput', false));
    %// 500x500 logical matrix
```

***Explanation:***

As previously (see the previous answer below), make use of the [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) command, but include the `'UniformOutput', false'` name-value pair such that the resulting `modes` is a `5x5` *cell* matrix (rather than a value matrix). After computing the modes, use a subsequent `cellfun` call to compute the logicals as per your specifications.

```
%// data
I = imread('DSM.tif');
c = mat2cell(I, [100,100,100,100,100], [100,100,100,100,100])
    %// 5x5 cell matrix with 100x100 data entries

%// modes: 5x5 cell matrix with single value entries (mode)
modes = cellfun(@(x) mode(x(:)), c, 'UniformOutput', false);

%// teste: 5x5 cell matrix with 100x100 logical (0/1) entries 
teste = cellfun(@ge, c, modes, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

The logicals in `teste` describes, for each value in each `100x100` data block, if the value is less than the mode value for the corresponding block:

```
0 : values in block less than block mode,
1 : values greater or equal to block mode.
```

Finally, if you want to convert the `5x5` cell array `teste` (with each cell holding `100x100` logical entries) to a single `500x500` logical matrix, you can make use of the [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) command, applied on cell matrix `teste`:

```
testeSingleValueMatrix = cell2mat(teste)
    %// 500x500 logical matrix
```

Now, by including a [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) command in a single `cellfun`, we can boil down the above to one single line; the condensed solution given in `(+)` above, namely

```
teste = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) bsxfun(@ge, x, mode(x(:))), c, 'UniformOutput', false));
    %// 500x500 logical matrix
```

---

## Answer previous to the edit of the original question (computing modes and assign into a *value* matrix)

You can make use of `cellfun` command

```
myCellMatrix = ... %// 5x5 cell matrix with 100x100 data entries
modes = cellfun(@(x) mode(x(:)), myCellMatrix);
```

Output will be a `5x5` value matrix containing the mode for each 100x100 data set.

Comment: Why uniformoutput false? The function returns a scalar. +1 for a good answer to the original question before it was edited.

Comment: I already have the mode of each cell. But how can I compare the value of each matrix 100x100 with the corresponding cell mode?

Comment: @PedroMarques I'm no longer at home and only at a mobile device; I can re-look at this question (after your edit) tomorrow, unless someone answers it for you before then.

Comment: @dfri thanks a lot for your help. I already edited the question with some changes.

Comment: Happy to help. I've updated my answer to cover the edit of your question (computing the logicals for `teste`). Note that the full computation of `teste` can, in the end, be performed in one single line, making use of the `cellfun` command (in junction with `bsxfun`).

Comment: I am so gratefull to you. You gave me the best and complete answer of all time. You're the best.

Comment: @PedroMarques Happy to help :)